# PHP/frontend interaction

Tags: php, apache, post

Having some trouble. New to web development. I'm trying to make a simple application that receives data from a Particle Photon board - using a webhook, everytime a particular event occurs on the board's end, a JSON is sent via POST. I'm running an Apache webserver. I want to process the POST request with PHP, and then have that PHP update what the user sees somehow. Right now I have only index.php, with the following:

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
      <body>
        <div>
          <?php
           if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
          { 
            $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
          // do something with $data
          }
          ?>
          
       </div>
     </body>
</html>
```

I'm not worried about input validation, I just want the rudimentary functionality. My thought process is that the webhook sends this POST request (it sends it to index.php, and appears to be working), and then the index.php will be triggered and then display the POST request information. I can't seem to get the index.php to receive the POST request. I've tried var_dump, echo, but it all comes back either blank or NULL. Is there something inherently flawed with my understanding of this setup?

This is the JSON that is being sent:

[image]

The only file I have on the server is index.php.

Comment: you need to access the [`$_POST[]`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) array first. At the moment though there isn't enough to go on here for a useful answer

Comment: where are you sending your post?

Comment: You will be unable to see theses posts, its sent in background. You need to prepare a script to receive it, process it and save the relevant data on a database. Later, when users access your site, you will show 'em the data from your database

Comment: Is there a way to do it without a database? I'm sending the post to the url that has index.php. All I really want is, as soon as the post is sent, have the "name" field in the JSON appear on the webpage.

Comment: @tjb272 I don't think so, you need something to store the post data processed. Don't expect to enable your users to access your index.php and wait from posts to be show dynamically, this will not happen unless you program your index.php to constantly do dynamic requests (aka ajax) checking for data to show to them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From comments:

First of all, prepare a process file, eg.: `process.php`, in this file you need only php code that check for a post, process it and store relevant data in your database.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST)){
    // Process post, store relevant data on database
}
```

Then, with data properly stored on database, you can show html pages to your users, retrieving data from database and showing to them accordingly.

Comment: So for this live updating, what would I use to query the database and display on the webpage? Is it possible with PHP?

Comment: Yes, PHP is required for you to do this, since you will query the database with it. But for the dynamic request you will need Javascript. There's plenty of tutorials on web about this. Just search google: Ajax + Jquery + PHP + MySQL and a lot of tutorials will came out

Comment: Got it. Thanks for all the help!